# Does solidity transfer command require fee

Tags: solidity

If I use the `transfer` command in solidity, for example:
`redeemer.transfer(amount);`

is there a fee involved?
That is, is a fee taken out from `amount`; or rather an extra fee taken from the contract invoking this command to cover the transfer?

Comment: Unless you program a fee, then no (except from extra instructions run that would up the gas used, which would increase the transaction cost)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fee involved in the sense that if you use transfer to send 1 ether, the receiving contract/address will receive 1 ether;
and the contract where transfer was invoked will only be charged 1 ether.

Now, calling the function that does the transfer will cost gas. Depending what the function does, it will cost more or less gas, which is paid in ether by the function caller. 
But again, in case the transfer command is invoked while calling a contract function, exactly 1 ether and no more will be reduced from the contract's balance.

So, for the person executing the function that does the transfer it will cost him the 1 ether being transferred + 0.0000x ether to pay for the gas.